# How can I speed up this histogram class?

Tags: c#, performance, image-processing, histogram

This is supposed to calculate the histogram of an 8-bit grayscale image.  With a 1024x770 test bitmap, CreateTime ends up at around 890ms.  How can I make this go (way, way) faster?

EDIT: I should mention that this doesn't actually compute the histogram yet, it only gets the values out of the bitmap.  So I really should have asked, what is the fastest way to retrieve all pixel values from an 8-bit grayscale image?

```
public class Histogram {

    private static int[,] values;

    public Histogram(Bitmap b) {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        values = new int[b.Width, b.Height];

        for (int w = 0; w < b.Width; ++w) {
            for (int h = 0; h < b.Height; ++h) {
                values[w, h] = b.GetPixel(w, h).R;
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        CreateTime = (sw.ElapsedTicks /
            (double)Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000;
    }

    public double CreateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the link posted by McWafflestix. I used to do this in C++ but when I tried to migrate my lib to C#, it was at that site that I learnt the C# tools to fast pixel access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic histogram algorithm is something like:

```
int[] hist = new hist[256];
//at this point dont forget to initialize your vector with 0s.

for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
   for(int j = 0 ; j < widthl ++j)
   {
        hist[ image[i,j] ]++;
   }
}
```

The algorithm sums how many pixels with value 0 you have, how many with value=1 and so on.
The basic idea is to use the pixel value as the index to the position of the histogram where you will count.

I have one version of this algorithm written for C# using unmanaged code (which is fast) I dont know if is faster than your but feel free to take it and test, here is the code:

```
    public void Histogram(double[] histogram, Rectangle roi)
    {
        BitmapData data = Util.SetImageToProcess(image, roi);

        if (image.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
            return;

        if (histogram.Length < Util.GrayLevels)
            return;

        histogram.Initialize();
        int width = data.Width;
        int height = data.Height;
        int offset = data.Stride - width;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* ptr = (byte*)data.Scan0;

            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x, ++ptr)
                    histogram[ptr[0]]++;

                ptr += offset;
            }
        }
        image.UnlockBits(data);         
    }

    static public BitmapData SetImageToProcess(Bitmap image, Rectangle roi)
    {
        if (image != null)
            return image.LockBits(
                roi,
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                image.PixelFormat);

        return null;
    }
```

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Right about the histogram, and right, that reading the pixels is the thing to optimize.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the Bitmap.LockBits method to access the pixel data.  [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx) is a good reference on the process.  Essentially, you're going to need to use `unsafe` code to iterate over the bitmap data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a copy/pastable version of the function I've come up w/ based on on this thread.

The unsafe code expects the bitmap to be Format24bppRgb, and if it's not, it'll convert the bitmap to that format and operate on the cloned version.

Note that the call to image.Clone() will throw if you pass in a bitmap using an indexed pixel format, such as Format4bppIndexed.

Takes ~200ms to get a histogram from an image 9100x2048 on my dev machine.

```
    private long[] GetHistogram(Bitmap image)
    {
        var histogram = new long[256];

        bool imageWasCloned = false;

        if (image.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
        {
            //the unsafe code expects Format24bppRgb, so convert the image...
            image = image.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            imageWasCloned = true;
        }

        BitmapData bmd = null;
        try
        {
            bmd = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                 PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            const int pixelSize = 3; //pixels are 3 bytes each w/ Format24bppRgb

            //For info on locking the bitmap bits and finding the 
            //pixels using unsafe code, see http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm
            int height = bmd.Height;
            int width = bmd.Width;
            int rowPadding = bmd.Stride - (width * pixelSize);
            unsafe
            {
                byte* pixelPtr = (byte*)bmd.Scan0;//starts on the first row
                for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                    {
                        histogram[(pixelPtr[0] + pixelPtr[1] + pixelPtr[2]) / 3]++;
                        pixelPtr += pixelSize;//advance to next pixel in the row
                    }
                    pixelPtr += rowPadding;//advance ptr to the next pixel row by skipping the padding @ the end of each row.
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bmd != null)
                image.UnlockBits(bmd);
            if (imageWasCloned)
                image.Dispose();
        }

        return histogram;
    }
```