# Accelerating bitmap grayscale conversion, is OpenMP an option in C#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, parallel-processing, openmp

please help me to make this code parallel  using openmp
this code is run on button click and the text box is 128

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IMG
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string path = "";
    public void openimage()
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.Clear(this.BackColor);
            Bitmap curBitmap = new Bitmap(path);
            g.DrawImage(curBitmap, 200, 220, 200, 200);
        }
    }
    Bitmap bm;
    Bitmap gs;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (path == "")
        {
            openimage();
        }

        //mack image gray scale
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(this.BackColor);
        // Create a Bitmap object
        bm = new Bitmap(path);
        // Draw image with no effects
        g.DrawImage(bm, 200, 220, 200, 200);


        gs = new Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height);
        for (int i = 0; i < bm.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bm.Height; j++)
            {
                Color c = bm.GetPixel(i, j);
                int y = (int)(0.3 * c.R + 0.59 * c.G + 0.11 * c.B);
                gs.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(y, y, y));
            }
        }

        // Draw image with no effects
        g.DrawImage(gs, 405, 220, 200, 200);


        for (int i = 0; i < gs.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gs.Height; j++)
            {
                Color c = gs.GetPixel(i, j);
                int y1 = 0;

                if (c.R >= Convert.ToInt16(textBox19.Text))
                    y1 = 255;
                bm.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(y1, y1, y1));

            }
        }
        g.DrawImage(bm, new Rectangle(610, 220, 200, 200), 0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        // Dispose of objects
        gs.Dispose();

        g.Dispose();
    }
 }
}
```

please help me as soon as u can i believe in this site and all programmers here...

Comment: The OpenMP spec covers only C, C++, and Fortran. No C#, and AFAIK Microsoft has not implemented anything like that in their C# compiler either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll hit a couple of speed-bumps if OpenMP is on your radar.  OpenMP is a multi-threading library for unmanaged C/C++, it requires compiler support to be effective.  Not an option in C#.

Let's take a step back.  What you've got now is as bad as you can possibly get.  Get/SetPixel() is dreadfully slow.  A major step would be to use Bitmap.LockBits(), it gives you an IntPtr to the bitmap bits.  You can party on those bits with an unsafe byte pointer.  That will be at least an order of magnitude faster.

Let's take another step back, you are clearly writing code to convert a color image to a gray-scale image.  Color transforms are natively supported by GDI+ through the ColorMatrix class.  That code could look like this:

```
public static Image ConvertToGrayScale(Image srce) {
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(srce.Width, srce.Height);
  using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
    var matrix = new float[][] {
        new float[] { 0.299f, 0.299f, 0.299f, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0.587f, 0.587f, 0.587f, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0.114f, 0.114f, 0.114f, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0,      0,      0,      1, 0 },
        new float[] { 0,      0,      0,      0, 1 }
    };
    var ia = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes();
    ia.SetColorMatrix(new System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(matrix));
    var rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, srce.Width, srce.Height);
    gr.DrawImage(srce, rc, 0, 0, srce.Width, srce.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
    return bmp;
  }
}
```

Credit to [Bob Powell: How to convert a colour image to grayscale](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145627/http://bobpowell.net/grayscale.aspx) for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make this code parallel? To gain processing efficiency (time) ? If so, I think before turning this code parallel you can try a different approach in the way you are accessing the pixel information in your image.

The way you are doing in this code is very slow. You may try to process your image using unsafe code to access the pixels of the Bitmap class.

Take a look [at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015170/how-can-i-speed-up-this-histogram-class/1015229#1015229) to see what I'm talking about