# convert 8 bit color bmp image to 8 bit grayscale bmp

Tags: c#, bitmap

This is my bitmap object

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(columns, rows, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
BitmapData bmd = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, columns, rows), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat);
```

How do i convert this into a 8 bit grayscale bitmap ?

Comment: Why are you using `LockBits`?

Comment: http://www.bobpowell.net/grayscale.htm

Comment: don't forget to mark one of the answer as accepted, after you check an see what works for you. Although all answer are basically the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you could change the color palette to a grayscale one

although the following code is in Vb.net. You could easily convert it to C#

```
Private Function GetGrayScalePalette() As ColorPalette  
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(1, 1, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)  

    Dim monoPalette As ColorPalette = bmp.Palette  

    Dim entries() As Color = monoPalette.Entries  

    Dim i As Integer 
    For i = 0 To 256 - 1 Step i + 1  
        entries(i) = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i)  
    Next 

    Return monoPalette  
End Function
```

Original Source -> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/vblanguage/thread/500f7827-06cf-4646-a4a1-e075c16bbb38

Comment: Unless the original image's palette was, by some complete miracle, already ordered by brightness, just assigning this palette to the image would completely mess it up.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, no need to change the pixels, just the palette is fine.  ColorPalette is a flaky type, this sample code worked well:

```
        var bmp = Image.FromFile("c:/temp/8bpp.bmp");
        if (bmp.PixelFormat != System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var newPalette = bmp.Palette;
        for (int index = 0; index < bmp.Palette.Entries.Length; ++index) {
            var entry = bmp.Palette.Entries[index];
            var gray = (int)(0.30 * entry.R + 0.59 * entry.G + 0.11 * entry.B);
            newPalette.Entries[index] = Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray);
        }
        bmp.Palette = newPalette;    // Yes, assignment to self is intended
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

I don't actually recommend you use this code, indexed pixel formats are a pita to deal with.  You'll find a fast and more general color-to-grayscale conversion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2039032/17034).

Comment: Is the 8 bit color palette entry always the same ? I thought you can use optimized ones to optimize the image. If its the same only i can use  var gray = (int)(0.30 * entry.R + 0.59 * entry.G + 0.11 * entry.B); right ?

Comment: Optimizing a palette is only relevant when you need to convert a 24bpp image to a 8bpp image.  Which requires mapping 16 million possible colors to only 256 available colors.  This is not what you asked for.

Comment: so that means C# puts in the default color palette always when creating a 8 bit image ?

Comment: Yes, GDI+ creates a default palette when you create a new 8bpp bitmap from scratch.  It is rare to actually do this, there's not much you can do with bitmaps that have one of the indexed pixel formats.  You can't draw into it.  A painting program is the typical source of 8bpp bitmaps.

Comment: This is not actually an "assignment to self" as the code comment says. The getter of the palette creates a new object, which is why this assignment at the end is necessary, and why the palette can't be edited directly with `bmp.Palette.Entries[index] = value;`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(columns, rows, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    {
       Color oc = b.GetPixel(i, x);
        int grayScale = (int)((oc.R * 0.3) + (oc.G * 0.59) + (oc.B * 0.11));
       Color nc = Color.FromArgb(oc.A, grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
       b.SetPixel(i, x, nc);
  }
}
BitmapData bmd = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, columns, rows), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat);
```

Comment: Is this only enough ? Dont you need to make changes to the color table ? Because still the modified bitmap data will still be using the same color table ?

Comment: Does `SetPixel` even work on indexed images? They have indexes as pixel values, not colours.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you want to do the same conversion as modern HDTVs, you'll want to use the Rec. 709 coefficients for the conversion. The ones provided above (.3, .59, .11) are (almost) the Rec. 601 (standard def) coefficients. The Rec. 709 coefficients are gray = 0.2126 R' + 0.7152 G' + 0.0722 B', where R', G', and B' are the gamma adjusted red, green, and blue components.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale) out. We did this at university and it works.

It is all you need with input and output.