# What does this java bitshift do?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I found some bitshift code in the [Java implementation of Hough Transform](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Java) on Rosetta code, I understand in general what the code does, except this part:

```
rgbValue = (int)(((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >>> 16) * 0.30 + ((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >>> 8) * 0.59 + (rgbValue & 0xFF) * 0.11);
```

I think it takes the average of all 3 pixels, that is at least what it looks like when I output the result. But how does this work? What are these magic numbers?

Method in which this function is used, pasted for convenience:

> ```
> public static ArrayData getArrayDataFromImage(String filename) throws  IOException
> {
>     BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
>     int width = inputImage.getWidth();
>     int height = inputImage.getHeight();
>     int[] rgbData = inputImage.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);
>     ArrayData arrayData = new ArrayData(width, height);
>     // Flip y axis when reading image
>     for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
>     {
>       for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
>       {
>         int rgbValue = rgbData[y * width + x];
>
>        // What does this do?
>         rgbValue = (int)(((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >>> 16) * 0.30 + ((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >>> 8) * 0.59 + (rgbValue & 0xFF) * 0.11);
>         arrayData.set(x, height - 1 - y, rgbValue);
>       }
>     }
>     return arrayData;
> }
> ```

Comment: The only caveat is that the integer truncation in this formula rounds down which gives a slight bias and makes the picture slightly darker than necessary. Probably better to do `rgbValue = (int)Math.round(((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >>> 16) * 0.30 + ((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >>> 8) * 0.59 + (rgbValue & 0xFF) * 0.11);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the trick that converts a 24-bit RGB value to a grayscale value using coefficients `0.3`, `0.59`, and `0.11` (note that these values add up to `1`).

This operation `(rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >>> 16` cuts out bits 17..24, and shifts them right to position 0..7, producing a value between 0 and 255, inclusive. Similarly, `(rgbValue & 0xFF00) >>> 8` cuts out bits 8..16, and shifts them to position 0..7.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8554448/335858) talks about the coefficients, and discusses other alternatives.