# Is there a convenient way to write 8-bit values to a BMP, then modify the colour palette in C++?

Tags: c++, image, bmp, colormap

I am trying to write 8-bit uints to a BMP file and add my own custom colour palette into the BMP header. I want to apply the colour palette through the optional colour table in the header and not change the greyscale values to RGB triples.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8605028/19142778) that uses C# to edit BMPs in this way but is there a C++ way? Or even something else that would be easy to add to the project?

[image: BMP Header specification]

Comment: You linked to an answer that links to an answer that answers your question

Comment: What seems to be the problem? If you've tried to do it, please share your code. Otherwise, please describe the problem in detail.