# Photo to grayscale in C#.NET and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I make this into a grayscale?

After much googling it seems the best I can do is change the tint of the picture (in the code bellow, it's a green tint). How can I do it?

```
byte[] redGreenBlueVal = new byte[numBytes];

for (int i = 0; i < redGreenBlueVal .Length; i += 4)
{
    redGreenBlueVal [i + 0] = (byte)(.114 * redGreenBlueVal [i + 0]); --> blue
    redGreenBlueVal [i + 1] = (byte)(.587 * redGreenBlueVal [i + 1]); --> green
    redGreenBlueVal [i + 2] = (byte)(.299 * redGreenBlueVal [i + 2]); --> red
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [parallel openmp c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038865/parallel-openmp-c-sharp)

Comment: Don't be surprised when you receive an `OutOfBounds` exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effect you're adjusting HSB so this should get you a better grayscale image:
30% RED
59% GREEN
11% BLUE

```
byte[] redGreenBlueVal = new byte[numBytes];

for (int i = 0; i < redGreenBlueVal .Length; i += 4)
{
      gray = (byte)(.11 * redGreenBlueVal [i + 0]);
      gray += (byte)(.59 * redGreenBlueVal [i + 1]); 
      gray += (byte)(.3 * redGreenBlueVal [i + 2]);

      redGreenBlueVal [i + 0] = gray;
      redGreenBlueVal [i + 1] = gray;
      redGreenBlueVal [i + 2] = gray;

}
```

Comment: I copied my code wrong. sorry, just edited (I'm taking this from an iOS app I wrote in Objective C so I didn't define 'gray' variable for you...)

Comment: Can you show some documentation? I can't see that being right. E.g `255,255,255 [WHITE]` would become `76.5, 150.45, 28.05 [NOT WHITE]`.

Comment: no, white would become white. your taking 30%, 59%, 11% of total saturation so it will still become 255,255,255

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting each pixels colour channels to the average value for that pixel.

i.e.

```
for( int i = 0; i < redGreenBlueVal.Length; += 4 )
{
    int average = (redGreenBlueVal[i + 0] + redGreenBlueVal[i + 1] + redGreenBlueVal[i + 2])/3;
    redGreenBlueVal[i + 0] = average;
    redGreenBlueVal[i + 1] = average;
    redGreenBlueVal[i + 2] = average;
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work because redGreenBlueVal is a byte, and you get overflow. You should probably convert to int before calculating the average.

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems obvious this can't work. (RGB)0,0,255 and (RGB)255,0,0 and (RGB)0,255,0 would all three become the same gray color which certainly isn't correct. You need to look at HSB/RGB calculations to understand that averages affect brightness and will not work

Answer (score 0):

To get a grayscale image, the basic idea is to have all the 3 channels hold the same value. There are many ways to do this, the simplest ones are:

- use only one of the channels (it will look like when you select individual channels in photoshop)
- calculate an average of the 3 channels