# Is there a faster method to convert bitmap pixels to greyscale?

Tags: vb.net, performance, bitmap, processing-efficiency

At the moment, I am using the `SetPixel()` method to change the colour of every pixel in a bitmap. This works fine on small images with small dimensions, but when I test it on large images it does take a while.

I haven't worked with images in VB.Net before, so I might just be overlooking something obvious. I'm doing this to make a program which converts an image to grey scale. This produces the right result but at a low speed, and during this time the UI freezes, so I'm keen to maximize the speed of conversion.

This is my code at the moment:

```
Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(img) '"img" is a reference to the original image 
For x As Integer = 0 To tmpImg.Width - 1
    For y As Integer = 0 To tmpImg.Height - 1
        Dim clr As Byte
        With tmpImg.GetPixel(x, y)
            clr = ConvertToGrey(.R, .G, .B)
        End With
        tmpImg.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(clr, clr, clr))
    Next
Next

Private Function ConvertToGrey(ByVal R As Byte, ByVal G As Byte, ByVal B As Byte) As Byte
    Return (0.2126 * R) + (0.7152 * B) + (0.0722 * G)
End Function
```

Comment: it might be faster to use a ColorMatrix or a library like AForge

Comment: @Plutonix thanks, I'll look into ColorMatrix but I'm hesitant to use a library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I convert bitmaps with OpenMP in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038865/can-i-convert-bitmaps-with-openmp-in-c)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing working code. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fast is a relative term, but this will convert a 480x270 image to greyscale in 10-12 ms (obviously system dependent) which does not seem unduly long.  I'm quite sure it will be faster than SetPixel.

```
Private Function GrayedImage(orgBMP As Bitmap) As Bitmap

    Dim grayscale As New Imaging.ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
        {New Single() {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0},
         New Single() {0.59, 0.59, 0.59, 0, 0},
         New Single() {0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0, 0},
         New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}})

    Dim bmpTemp As New Bitmap(orgBMP)
    Dim grayattr As New Imaging.ImageAttributes()
    grayattr.SetColorMatrix(grayscale)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpTemp)
        g.DrawImage(bmpTemp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmpTemp.Width, bmpTemp.Height), 
                    0, 0, bmpTemp.Width, bmpTemp.Height, 
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel, grayattr)
    End Using

    Return bmpTemp
End Function
```

Values are rounded from .299, .587, .114

Comment: time is ~80ms for a 1280*720 image.  I dont have a problem with that considering what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks, I've never even known about `ColorMatrix` before, and looking into it I've discovered that it is incredibly complicated. However the results are brilliant, I got **1028 milliseconds (~1 second)** on a **3008 x 2000** image, whereas I _was_ getting **297273 milliseconds (4 mins 57 seconds)** on the same image. Clearly a massive improvement, I'll just have to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf7sa87(v=vs.110).aspx) until I get it.