# Faster way to do get/set pixel with powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, bitmap, draw

So I got two functions, one that analyze an image if it's grayscale and one that convert an image to grayscale. These use .NET System.Drawing.Bitmap GetPixel and SetPixel.
It works but is quite slow and I read some that you lock the bitmap in memory for faster work.

Found some examples in C# but since having no experiencing in C# I'm a bit lost.
example http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing2.php

Is it possible to do this in powershell?

here's the fuctions in powershell:

```
Function Test-ImageGrayScale {
    $error.clear()
    $filename = $image
    $image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $filename
    

    #keep count of the values
    $red = 0
    $green = 0
    $blue = 0
    $total = 0

    foreach ($x in 0..($image.Width - 1)) {
        foreach ($y in 0..($image.Height - 1)) {

            $pixelColor = $image.GetPixel($x, $y)
            $red += $pixelColor.R
            $green += $pixelColor.G
            $blue += $pixelColor.B
            $total++

        }
    }

    #Calculate average
    $red /= $total
    $green /= $total
    $blue /= $total

    if ($red -eq $green -or $green -eq $blue -or $red -eq $blue) {
        Write-Output "Image is Grayscale!"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "Image is in Color!"
    }

}


    Function Convert-GrayScale {
    
   $filename = Get-ChildItem $image
   $image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $image

   # Output Image
    $bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($image.Width, $image.Height)

    
        foreach ($x in 0..($image.Width - 1)) {
            foreach ($y in 0..($image.Height - 1)) {
                $pixelColor = $image.GetPixel($x, $y)
                $red = $pixelColor.R
                $green = $pixelColor.G
                $blue = $pixelColor.B
                $gray = ($red * .2126) + ($green * .7152) + ($blue * .0722)
                $bitmap.SetPixel($x, $y, [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($gray, $gray, $gray))
            }
        }
    
        $global:outFile = $Outpath + "\" + "GrayScale_" + $filename.basename + ".jpg"
        $bitmap.Save($global:outFile)
    
        $bitmap.Dispose()
    
    }
```

Comment: You could reinvent the wheel, but would'n it be easier to install [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) and use it with `magick $fileIn -grayscale Rec709Luminance $fileOut` to produce a grayscale image?

Comment: yes but what's the fun in that ;)

Comment: `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` do a `LockBits` operation on the bitmap internally, and that is the slowdown. If you simply lock the bitmap once, do all your operations, and then unlock it, it should speed things up considerably. Do note that unless you work with Marshal class you'd be working with raw pointers. I'm not sure what exactly you can do from powershell; I only know this stuff in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be faster:

```
function ConvertTo-GrayScale {
    # adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038865/accelerating-bitmap-grayscale-conversion-is-openmp-an-option-in-c
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]$Path
    )
    $bitmap     = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile($Path)
    $grayBitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::new($bitmap.Width, $bitmap.Height)
    $graphics   = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($grayBitmap)
    $rect       = [System.Drawing.Rectangle]::new(0, 0, $bitmap.Width, $bitmap.Height)
    $unit       = [System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel

    # create a grayscale matrix
    [single[][]] $matrix = (0.299, 0.299, 0.299, 0, 0),
                           (0.587, 0.587, 0.587, 0, 0),
                           (0.114, 0.114, 0.114, 0, 0),
                           (0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                           (0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

    $colorMatrix = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix]::new($matrix)
    $attributes  = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes]::new()
    $attributes.SetColorMatrix($colorMatrix)

    # draw the original image on to the new one, using the grayscale color matrix
    $graphics.DrawImage($bitmap, $rect, 0, 0, $bitmap.Width, $bitmap.Height, $unit, $attributes)

    # create a new name for the image by appending `_gray` to the basename
    $fileIn  = Get-Item -Path $Path
    $fileOut = '{0}_gray{1}' -f (Join-Path -Path $fileIn.DirectoryName -ChildPath $fileIn.BaseName), $fileIn.Extension
    # save the grayscaled image
    $grayBitmap.Save($fileOut)

    #clean-up
    $graphics.Dispose()
    $grayBitmap.Dispose()
    $attributes.Dispose()
    $bitmap.Dispose()
}
```

---

New version to accept a series of files so you can pipe directly from `Get-ChildItem`:

```
function ConvertTo-GrayScale {
    # adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038865/accelerating-bitmap-grayscale-conversion-is-openmp-an-option-in-c
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string[]]$Path
    )
    begin {
        # create a grayscale matrix
        [single[][]] $matrix = (0.299, 0.299, 0.299, 0, 0),
                               (0.587, 0.587, 0.587, 0, 0),
                               (0.114, 0.114, 0.114, 0, 0),
                               (0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                               (0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

        # to make the colors inverted for a negative image, use
        # [single[][]] $matrix = (-1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                               # (0, -1, 0, 0, 0),
                               # (0, 0, -1, 0, 0),
                               # (0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                               # (0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

        $colorMatrix = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix]::new($matrix)
        $attributes  = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes]::new()
        $attributes.SetColorMatrix($colorMatrix)
        $unit        = [System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel
    }
    process {
        foreach ($file in $Path) {
            Write-Verbose "Processing file '$file'"
            $bitmap     = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile($file)
            $grayBitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::new($bitmap.Width, $bitmap.Height)
            $graphics   = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($grayBitmap)
            $rect       = [System.Drawing.Rectangle]::new(0, 0, $bitmap.Width, $bitmap.Height)

            # draw the original image on to the new one, using the grayscale color matrix
            $graphics.DrawImage($bitmap, $rect, 0, 0, $bitmap.Width, $bitmap.Height, $unit, $attributes)

            # create a new name for the image by appending `_gray` to the basename
            $fileIn  = Get-Item -Path $file
            $fileOut = '{0}_gray{1}' -f (Join-Path -Path $fileIn.DirectoryName -ChildPath $fileIn.BaseName), $fileIn.Extension
            # save the grayscaled image
            Write-Verbose "Saving file '$fileOut'"
            $grayBitmap.Save($fileOut)

            #clean-up
            $graphics.Dispose()
            $grayBitmap.Dispose()
            $bitmap.Dispose()
        }
    }
    end {
        $attributes.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Test -File | ConvertTo-GrayScale -Verbose
```

Comment: Thanks, had to change $filename to $path since it's the param. I did a measure and a quite large picture took 14 seconds with my old way and 861 miliseconds with your script :)

Comment: by the way is there a faster way to detect if image is in grayscale or not?

Comment: @Anthon Thanks. I haven't figured out a faster way to test if an image is grayscale or not yet... That might be more difficult than it seems. Probably, you don't test every pixel, but a random subset across the images surface. Not 100% then, of course.. Perhaps some formats have attributes that can tell, but then still it would only apply to those formats..

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried to not test all pixels and it's a lot faster and seems to work but might not be 100%.

Comment: @Anthon I'll keep fiddling with it though. Who knows one of us finds a suitable answer to that. BTW you were right about the parameter name. I mistakenly used `$filename` in the code where it should have been `$Path`. I have also posted another version that accepts multiple files to process.